# Dell Inspiron 1210 mini Blank Screen on boot 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, screen, inspiron

Dell Inspiron 1210 mini Blank Screen on boot 12.04

If I mash buttons I get to a gray screen then the login screen and into the desktop but normally I turn on the laptop and I see a black screen with a cursor then a purple screen then it just goes black. I can hit ctrl alt F1 or F2 and get a prompt. I've tried using the poulsbo ppa driver script fix but that doesn't work.

I don't knwo what to do now. I have the OS installed and when I did get into the OS by mashing buttons I installed updates and wireless adapter drivers. It works but if I reboot I jsut get to the black screen and have no idea what to do. What needs to be done so that I can just boot up and see the login screen!?

Answer (score 1):

Did some research and found that ctrl alt F7 will bring up the display, as wonky as it is with the ghosting and cropped display area, so there's that... Just really need help finding a suitable display driver that will make my experience better.

I ran into this issue on an old inspiron 1100. I have no idea why I thought things would be different on an inspiron 1210... :( Oh, Dell...

Answer (score 1):

I found that logging in 2D fixed the problem on 12.10. (On the login screen, click the Ubuntu logo and select *Ubuntu 2D* instead of *Ubuntu*. Then log in.) Must be a Compiz problem?